# Is it possible to change MS paint's default save file type to PNG

Tags: windows, file-extension, file-types, microsoft-paint

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to set default file format for MS Paint](https://superuser.com/questions/145130/how-to-set-default-file-format-for-ms-paint)
>   [How do I make Windows pbrush default to a save-as JPG format?](https://superuser.com/questions/6684/how-do-i-make-windows-pbrush-default-to-a-save-as-jpg-format)

PNG is better than BMP in my work and I too often forgot to change the file type before clicking save.

Comment: that question was closed. and there is no solution on the linked question. Per http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/ such dupes are encouraged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no easy tweak for this to my knowledge. There is, however, the old trick to opening it with a blank file by default. Create a small blank PNG file and place it somewhere that won't get deleted, such as the system32 folder.

Open your mspaint shortcut and change the target to open this PNG as an argument to the mspaint executable.

eg.

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\mspaint.exe "C:\WINDOWS\System32\blank.PNG"
```

Everything that's pasted into a new paint window will be saved in PNG format by default.

Don't forget to make this blank PNG read only to avoid saving over it each time accidentally ;)

Comment: Didn't realize I answered this before myself lmfao. You're welcome however.

Comment: nice. When I click new the new file will be png as well :)

Comment: @Louis: Another option is to upgrade to Windows 7, as .png is the default filetype in Paint now, whch itself is much improved.

Comment: yeah, except that I can't force my office to upgrade :P