# Paint for Windows seven 64 bits: How to change the default save format from png to jpg

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, jpeg, png, microsoft-paint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to change MS paint's default save file type to PNG](https://superuser.com/questions/215173/is-it-possible-to-change-ms-paints-default-save-file-type-to-png)

1. When I copy an image in Paint and want so save it, the default format is png. How is it possible to set the default format to jpg?
2. In the same software, is it possible to add buttons such as "save as" for instance?

Answer (score 1):

I don`t think it is possible. I suggest using [infanview](http://www.irfanview.com/). It is very useful and light.

Comment: with irfanview you cannot edit images as in ms paint, but only apply some filters and do some other transformations.