# Default saving type on paint windows 7

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-paint

I saw questions about changing default saving file type on Windows XP paint, but couldn't find about Windows 7, so can I change default saving type from PNG to JPG?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best option is go to Save As, right click on JPEG picture, then Add to quick access toolbar.

[image: Adding save as jpg to quick access]

Not exactly ctrl+s convenient, but now you have a little icon that saves directly to jpg.

Also, [How can I make Windows Paint save by default as JPEG format?](https://superuser.com/questions/6684/how-can-i-make-windows-paint-save-by-default-as-jpeg-format)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to do this in paint. You will manually have to click to tell it to save it as jpg.